# Is it possible to construct a derived class in the abstract base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

Suppose you have the following three classes (I left out the implementations):

```
abstract class BaseClass
class Derived1 : BaseClass
class Derived2 : BaseClass
```

Now, in the `BaseClass` I want to define a method that is supposed to return a new, slightly modified version of the same instance. But here's the problem: I can't construct `BaseClass` because it is abstract, and I can't know which derived class you're using because we're in `BaseClass`.

The only workaround I can think of is to make it an abstract method, and make every derived class implement its own version of it. But that would be a lot of repeated code just with just one class name changed. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Just for info, if you call `.GetType()` from within the abstract `BaseClass`, the type returned will be the `Derived` class. So the `BaseClass` should know which derived class your using.

Comment: What’s wrong with new Derived2(); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using generic types?

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public T GetSlightlyModifiedInstance<T>() where T : new, BaseClass
    {
        return new T(); // Do whatever there
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like so

```
Derived1 derived1 = new Derived1();
Derived2 derived2 = new Derived2();

Derived1 modifiedDerived1 = derived1.GetSlightlyModifiedInstance<Derived1>();
Derived2 modifiedDerived2 = derived2.GetSlightlyModifiedInstance<Derived2>();
```